# Redshift compression recommendations differ from analyze compression

Tags: amazon-web-services, encoding, compression, amazon-redshift

My Redshift cluster is showing me some compression related recommendations such as:

```
ALTER TABLE "schema"."table" ALTER COLUMN "field_a" ENCODE lzo;
```

But when I do:

```
ANALYZE COMPRESSION schema.table;
```

The output shows something like this:

```
table,id,az64,0.00
table,date,raw,0.00
table,field_a,lzo,0.00
table,field_b,lzo,0.00
table,field_c,zstd,41.92
table,field_d,zstd,36.95
table,field_e,zstd,84.74
table,field_f,az64,0.00
```

As you can see the `field_a` which is the field in the recommendation in the `AWS` dashboard will benefit with an estimated 0%, and even more, the field is already compressed with `lzo` compression type so it's not event real the recommendation.

On the other hand, other fields that are not in the recommendation will benefit in a huge percentage of applying compression.

Why is this `redshift` recommendation focusing in only one field and the `analyze` statement returns different result?

If I apply `ENCODE` on `field_c`, `field_d` and `field_e` the benefit will be in `I/O disk workload` and `disk usage`, but data or speed in queries will be affected in bad way or it's totally harmless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things to check as Redshift has a number of systems in this area.  First, how old was the console recommendation?  Also does the table have "Automatic Table Optimization" enabled?

Analyze compression just looks as the size the column can be reduced to if the compression is changes.  So just about size and as you rightly point out IO bandwidth.  The reason that the improvement could be 0% is likely due to how the data falls into 1MB blocks and no blocks are saved by making the data smaller (at least at the current size of the table).

The console recommendation is a "smarter" algorithm - it looks at more than data size and tries to make "safe" recommendations or change.  The major reason that improving a compression can reduced performance is by making the block metadata less effective.  So if a column is often used as a WHERE clause Redshift will shy away from recommending additional compression.  I've yet to see it be smart enough to look through metadata impacts and compare them correctly with IO bandwidth improvements.  So it just gets shy when it isn't sure.

In the case of these other columns where analyze compression says large amounts of size savings are possible it is possible Redshift is being "shy".  Are these columns used as WHERE clauses?  Especially simple WHERE clauses (col = value) where metadata comparisons are enabled.  Just because Redshift didn't recommend these changes to encodings doesn't mean that these are bad to do (or good, or neutral).  It just doesn't know enough / isn't smart enough.  There are ways to analyze the metadata for these columns and see what the different encodings will do to it but this takes some effort.  ENCODE RAW for common, simple WHERE clause columns is a good guess but to know for sure takes work.

Comment: thanks for your response.

Recommendations were for 2 days ago.
Table doesn't have automatic table optimization.

I understand what you say, then, a good option is to check if this columns that reduce_pct is over 50% i.e, are used in where statements, if they are used, better to kew as raw. Otherwise they can be encoded to specific encoding?

Comment: That would be the simple approach.  I would add that you want to "keep commonly used WHERE clauses" as raw vs. all WHERE clause columns, or you can end up with everything encoded as raw and loose a lot of IO bandwidth.   A not-too-complex step that can be added is to look at the column's metadata and see if there is any "value" to keeping it as raw.

Comment: mm interesting, when you say look column' metadata what you mean? what should I search for?

Comment: The stv_blocklist table allows you to peek at the metadata for the table and stores minvalue and maxvalue for all blocks for each column for each table.  Now these values are encoded as BIGINT which is great for numbers but not so great for dates and strings - I worked out a reverse decode a while back and should write a white paper about it.  So if the table's metadata is up to date (analyze) then you can see how the range of values for the blocks in a column overlap or represent nearly independent ranges of values.  Metadata that has independent ranges are of value for WHERE clause checks.

Comment: If there is high levels of overlap in block metadata then there is no value to leaving the column as raw - the metadata check is ineffective and won't get worse (but IO bandwidth consumption will be reduced by compressing).  However if moving from raw to compressed greatly increases the overlap then the effectiveness of the metadata check will impacted and query performance could decline greatly.

Comment: didn't know that. Very great contribution. Thank you very much.

Comment: A big part of sort key selection and all of the compress vs. uncompressed columns is about the effectiveness of metadata.